# My list of listings isn't generated

Tags: listings, tufte

I know there are some 'similar' questions but none worked for me.
I am using tufte-book.cls template and also the 'listings' package to include code listings.
For some reason the 'list of listings' stays empty, even though everything else works.

I have a multi file project but the 2 files really needed to reproduce the problem are:

1. main.tex (main file)
2. chapter1.tex (referred to from main)

My stripped-down project (which still has the problem) is as below:

File: main.tex

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class

\usepackage{booktabs} % Better horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{graphicx} % Needed to insert images into the document
\graphicspath{{graphics/}} % Sets the default location of pictures

\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage} % Command to insert a blank page

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code

\lstloadlanguages{Java} % Load Java syntax for listings, for a list of other languages supported see: ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf
\lstset{language=Java, % Use Java in this example
        frame=tb, % t=top, b=bottom, l=left, r=right
        numbers=left, % Line numbers on left
        firstnumber=1, % Line numbers start with line 1
        numberstyle=\small\color{Blue}, %\tiny\color{Blue}, % Line numbers are blue and small
        stepnumber=1 % Line numbers go in steps of 1
}

% Creates a new command to include Java code, the first parameter is the filename of the code (without .java), the second parameter is the caption

\newcommand{\javacode}[2]{
\lstinputlisting[caption=#2,label=#1]{#1.java}
}

\title{Hello World} % Title of the book

\author[~]{First Last} % Author

\publisher{Good Books Press} % Publisher

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle % Print the title page

\lstlistoflistings % Print a list of listings

\chapter{Introduction} % The asterisk leaves out this chapter from the table of contents

\section{A book}
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\mainmatter

\include{chapter1}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

File: chapter1.tex

```
\chapter{My Chapter 1}
\label{ch:1}

\newthought{Let's get our feet wet.} Mpla mpla.

\section{Hello World!}
\label{sec:hello_world}

A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\javacode{java/HelloWorld}{Java implementation of Hello World}

Testing with a reference to Listing \ref{java/HelloWorld}.

A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test 2,label=test2]  % Start your code-block

Some code
More code
\end{lstlisting}

A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

The only missing file is tufte-book.cls which is the standard one.

Comment: Do your listings have a `caption=` option at all?

Comment: Please do not link to external sources, add the minimal working example to the question (edit).

Comment: In you files from the link there are no listings.

Comment: Yes there is a listing. See macro '\javacode' line 11 in 'chapte1.tex'.

Comment: I edited the question to eliminate the link to Dropbox. Also I minimized the project further (problem is still there). Finally I have added a 2nd listing (the first is in file chapter1.tex line 11, and the other is in the same file lines 17-21.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes I have a caption (and a label for that matter). I can even refer to the listings using `\ref` as shown in my edited question.

Comment: Your example would be even better if you removed the `\javacode`, as it stands the code relies on the file `Helloworld.java`. In fact, `\documentclass{tufte-book} \usepackage{listings} \begin{document} \lstlistoflistings \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test 2] Some code \end{lstlisting} \end{document}` is enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Nearchos: Your example is not compilable since we do not have the java code :-(

Comment: apparently `tufte-book` is the culprit

Comment: Apologies for this. In reality any file named HelloWorld.java is enough (I mean its content is irrelevant as long as it is text, like 'Hello world'). But we can eliminate the first listing altogether (the one with a reference to the JAVA file) and the problem is still there as mentioned in an earlier comment.

Comment: I suspect that `titletoc` and other unhealthy features of `tufte-book` screw up the ToC generation.

Comment: I guess my options then are to do without the 'list of listings' or give up on tufte-book. I will have to think about it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code (I include two lines of your example so you know where to do the addition):

```
\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tufte@class}{book}}
    {\chapter *{\lstlistlistingname}}
    {\section *{\lstlistlistingname}}%
  \@starttoc{lol}%
}
\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
\let\l@lstlisting\@tufte@lof@line
\makeatother

\lstloadlanguages{Java} % Load Java syntax for listings
```

After this you will get

[image]